# I can't return an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have an object like this:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'john',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Foo'
    },
    {
      name: 'Bar',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Doe'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have to create a function to find the object with the specified name.
My code can find the object with the name, but it doesn't return the object.

```js
const search = (node, name) => {
  return searchInObj(node, name);
};

const searchInObj = (obj, name) => {
  if (obj.name === nodeName) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    if (obj.children) {
      searchInArr(obj.children, name);
    }
  }
};

const searchInArr = (arr, name) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    searchInObj(arr[i], name);
  }
};
```

If I put

```js
console.log(search(obj, 'Doe')) // return undefined
```

It just work if I looking for `john`

Comment: You're missing some `return` statements

Comment: Did you try debugging your function ? Also, I would use `Array.prototype.some` to search in children array instead of adding `searchInArr` there. The recursion then will take place in searchInObj. Also, an `undefined` as a return value indicates a missing return statement as Quentin pointed out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Return the result for searchInObj function.

```js
  const obj = {
  name: 'john',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Foo'
    },
    {
      name: 'Bar',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Doe'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const search = (node, name) => {
  return searchInObj(node, name);
};

const searchInObj = (obj, name) => {
  if (obj.name === name) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    if (obj.children) {
      return searchInArr(obj.children, name);
    }
  }
};

const searchInArr = (arr, name) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const result = searchInObj(arr[i], name);
    if (result !== undefined) return result
  }
};

console.log(search(obj, 'Doe')) ///This will return object
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `return` statements, like @quentin said

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'john',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Foo'
    },
    {
      name: 'Bar',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Doe'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const search = (node, name) => {
  return searchInObj(node, name);
};

const searchInObj = (obj, name) => {
  // Typo here? what is nodeName
  if (obj.name === name) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    if (obj.children) {
      // Added return 
      return searchInArr(obj.children, name);
    }
  }
};

const searchInArr = (arr, name) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // Return if found
    const result = searchInObj(arr[i], name);
    if (result !== undefined) return result
  }
};

console.log(search(obj, 'Doe'))
```